# looking for a particular document style

Tags: document-classes

What is the LaTeX document class for a document that has sections numbered numerically like 2.3.2.4, 2.3.2.5, etc.? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Do you mean `section`s? Or subsections? Or `subsubsections`? Most classes can do that, given that `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}` is used and it has a `chapter.section.subsection.subsubsection` hierarchy

Comment: Second book, third part, second chapter, fourth and fifth section?

Comment: almost every latex class numbers sections/subsections in that way, certainly the standard article, report and book classes.

Comment: Sorry, I was confused. I was using a specialized document class, and I forgot that the standard classes can do that.

Comment: @Russ apart from `letter` classes I would have thought pretty much all latex classes have hierarchical  numbering like this. It is built in to latex so a class would have to actively disable it.

Comment: Many journals use a different style, such as using letters rather than numbers for subsections.

Comment: @Russ sure but if chapters are using ABC then it's only `\renewcommaand\thechapter{\arabic{chapter}}` to  make it use 123 so a question about which _class_ supports  hierarchical numbering is a little strange. Whatever class is being used you can usually change the numbering style fairly trivially, it is not a feature of the class unless the class has disabled latex's numbering systems and implemented something else (which is possible of course)

Comment: It's not just a matter of translating letters to numbers and vice versa. For example, some journals will have a section labeled 1, then subsections labeled A, B, etc. (not 1A or 1.A). In any case, I was confused, and the issue is now resolved.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Indeed `novel` actively disables it. But this class would not be used for the indicated application.

Answer (score 2):

almost all latex classes will do this but you may have to increase `secnumdepth` so that lower level section headings are numbered.

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\begin{document}

\chapter{zzz}
zz
\section{Zzzzz}
zz
\chapter{Zzzzzz}
zz
\section{zZZz}
zz
\subsection{ZzzZz z}
zz
\subsection{ZzzZz z z}
zz
\section{zZZzzzz}
zz
\subsection{Zz zZz z z}
zz
\section{zZZzzzz}
zz
\subsection{ZzzZ}
zz
\subsection{ZzzZZZz}
zz
\subsubsection{ZzzZ}
zz
\subsubsection{ZzzZZZzz}
zz
\subsubsection{ZzzZZZzzz}
zz
\subsubsection{ZzzZZZzzzz}
zz
\subsubsection{ZzzZZZzzzz}
zz


\end{document}
```

Comment: Looking at the screen shot I get sleepy... somehow ;-)